# AppStore keeps telling me to update XCode

Tags: xcode, app-store

I have updated my XCode to the latest 5.0 version. But recently I noticed that the AppStore still offering update-option for the XCode. When I checked the installed XCode version, it shows 5.0. What's that suppose to mean? Has it been updated or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the computer, then open the App Store back up and if it is still there then it is nothing to worry about.